# how to pass id to controller using onclick function in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

This is my code. 
I want to pass Id to use in the controller for delete

```
<button onclick="Delete(<?php echo $article->id; ?>)">Delete</button>
```

And this is function through which the `id` is passed to the controller

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Delete(id)
    {

      var conf=confirm('Are you want to delete');
      if (conf) 
      {
          $.ajax({
          url:'admin/delet_data',
          type:"post",
          data:{dlt_id:id},
          });
      }

    }
  </script>
```

I want the `id` in this function

```
 public function delet_data()
{
    echo $this->input->post('dlt_id'); exit;    
}
```

Comment: And what exactly does not work with the given code?

Comment: i want access this dlt_id in this function delet_data()

Comment: whats the issue you are facing?

Comment: Have you checked whether the data was properly submitted to the backend? Is the markup generated properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

concatenate the id with url

**js**

```
 url:'admin/delet_data'+id,
```

then use function like this in controller

**Controller**

```
public function delet_data($id)
{
    echo $id;
}
```